# Plot and save YOLO graphs into Json or other format so the graphs can be compared with other models

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, graph, yolo

I'm new to the Python programming language, please help

i use custom data set and train the model with this code in python using yolov8(ultralytics )

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
results = model.train(
data='pothole_v8.yaml', imgsz=1280,epochs=50,batch=8,name='yolov8n_v8_50e')
```

but my problem is, I don't know how to save the training result graph into JSON or other format.
which is the JSON I'll use to create the comparison chart (as shown below).

[Comparison between 3 model graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeLn4.png)

requires additional code on python so that training results can be stored in JSON and the 3 model can be compared